# I need to left justify and right justify within a column using CSS

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a web page that lists names and dates of members.  This is a fairly long list, and I've broken it into two columns.  At this point, it's just static using CSS to create the columns, but I need to make part of the column justify left (the name of the person), and the date justify right within the column.  I'm not really sure how to approach this, other than actually creating 4 columns. At some point in the future I'd like to have my page import the information from an XML document, but that's down the road.

CSS:

```
    div#content
{
    text-indent:3em;
    padding: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:225px;
    top:280px;
    float:left;
    width:555px;
    padding-bottom: 1em;

}

.colleft{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   left: 10px;
}

.col1
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 275px;
    float:left;

}

.col2
{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 275px;
    float:left;

}
```

HTML:

```
        <DIV id="content"> 
        <DIV id="title">
            <H2>
                <B>My List</B>
            </H2>
        </DIV>
        <DIV class="colleft">
            <DIV class="col1">
                <BR>John Q Public   1869,1870,1872*
                John Smith  1871,1872*<BR>
                Johny Appleseed     1873<BR>
```

Comment: Use `float` left/right.

Comment: It's tabular data...use a table.

Comment: You'll most likely want to use a table for this sort of data. It will make organising and styling the data easier. Otherwise, if you want to use the existing HTML structure, you could throw a <span> onto the date text.

`John Q Public  <span>1869,1870,1872</span>`

And text-align:right the data in the <span>:

`.col1 span { text-align: right; }`